# The word מלשינות in the second יהי רצון after ברכות השחר

Tags: tefilla, vowels-nekudot

In the second יהי רצון prayer that is customarily included in ברכות השחר (the prayer of רבי which he would say בתר צלותיה from :ברכות טז), there seem to be two variant vocalizations for the word מלשינות. Some siddurim have מלשינוּת and some have מלשינוֹת. Would the first be an abstract noun referring to the act in general, and the second be a concrete feminine plural referring to women who do that? Or, is the second just a different way of spelling the first?

Comment: Wery intresting because edus sheker, sin'as ha briot suggest that malshinus is right

Comment: That's a good point, @kouty. But wouldn't it be הלשנה ?

Comment: fine!  But meadam ra myetrer ra mishachen ra... Some people say  meisha raa,  so malshinot must be there.  On the other hand for moyser we say moserot

Comment: In mishnayot pea there's Namoshot

Comment: @kouty, I don't understand.

Comment: The names of mosrim is  sometimes called moserot so maybe the same principle for malshinim the malshinot